# Android: Create a loop-able tone

Tags: java, android, audio

I have been trying to generate a tone (444 hz, 1000 hz, etc) and then play it in Android. My first searches gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android) stack overflow question. While this works great given a duration, I would prefer to make the duration infinite (loop-able).

First I used only use integer values for the tone, because this would mean that I could use 1 second and it should loop properly. However there are still some frequencies that don't loop right.

Second I thought I could only calculate 1 period of the sine wave, and then loop that. However I found out [that is not a viable approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118922/generate-a-single-period-of-a-frequency)

How can I, given any frequency, generate a tone that I can loop?

Comment: what do you use to play audio?

Comment: Arrays of `byte`s pushed to an `AudioTrack`

Comment: Hi @Flynn, How did a loop with 16-bit PCM? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436187/how-to-change-the-duration-of-the-audiotrack-by-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread that will run your tone every period of time(for example 2sec.):

```
private Runnable startSoundRunnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_AUTOREDIAL_LITE, 2000);
        sleep(2000);
      } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
  }
};

// Run thread
new Thread(startSoundRunnable).start();
```